# General solution of ODE $y'\cot(x)+y=2$ with integration constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'\cot(x)+y=2$

Given the above, my steps to finding the general solution:

${dy\over dx}\cot(x)=2-y$

${dy\over (2-y)}=\tan(x)dx$

Integrating both sides

$\int{1\over (2-y)}dy=\int \tan(x)dx$

$-\ln\lvert2-y\rvert=-\ln\lvert\cos(x)\rvert+C$

${1\over (2-y)}=C\sec(x)$

General solution

$y=2-{\cos(x)\over C}$

Now I need to find the integration constant using the initial condition $y(0)=1$

Is that just a case of inputting $y=1$, $x=0$, and solving for $C$?

Comment: $y(x) = 2 + c \cos x$, $y(0) = 2 + c = 1 \implies c = -1 \implies y(x) = 2 - \cos x$.

Comment: except... $\cot(x)$ is not defined at $0$. I never liked teachers and textbooks that play loose with such things.

Comment: Indeed. And in the present case, the fix is easy, which is to ask to solve $y'\cos x+y\sin x=2\sin x$ instead, or even $y'+y\tan x=2\tan x$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to attempt the problem is to the following: \begin{equation} y'\cot(x) +y =2 \end{equation} To begin the attempt one can do the following: \begin{align}y'\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}+y&=2 \\ y'\cos(x)+\sin(x)y&=2\sin(x) \end{align} The equation now becomes separable: \begin{align}y'\cos(x)&=2\sin(x)-\sin(x)y \\ y'\cos(x)&=\sin(x)(2-y) \\ \frac{dy}{dx}\cos(x)&=\sin(x)(2-y)\\ \frac{dy}{2-y}&=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}dx \\ \int \frac{dy}{2-y}&= \int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}dx \\ -\ln(2-y)&=-\ln(\cos(x))+C \\ \frac{1}{2-y}&=\frac{1}{c \cos(x)} \\ c\cos(x)&=2-y \\ 2+c\cos(x)&=y \end{align} Solving for the initial condition one gets the following: \begin{align}1&=2+c\cos(0) \\ -1&=c \end{align} Therefore the equation is the following: \begin{equation} y= 2 -\cos(x) \end{equation}