# Is there a special way to solve a problem like this with the indicated setup?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

[My Answer, and the Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3698207/372659)

My question is if the problem was converted to the following:\begin{align}\cos(x)y'+\sin(x)y&=2\sin(x)\\ u'y'+uy&=2u \end{align} How can I advance from here to solve the problem if substitution were my aim in answering the question (which of course is answered)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach,
$$u'y'+uy=2u$$
$$uy'-u'y=-2u'\quad (\text{where, } \ \ u=\cos x)$$
$$\frac{y'}{u}-\frac{u'}{u^2}y=-2\frac{u'}{u^2}\quad (\text{dividing by } \ u^2)$$
$$d\left(\frac{y}{u}\right)=2 \ d\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$$
$$\int d\left(\frac{y}{u}\right)=2\int d\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$$
$$\frac yu=\frac2u+C$$
$$y=Cu+2$$

**Alternatively,**
$$\cos(x)y'+\sin (x)y=2\sin(x)$$
$$y'+\tan (x)y=2\tan(x)$$
Multiplying $\sec x$ on both the sides,
$$y'\sec (x)+\sec(x)\tan (x)y=2\sec(x)\tan(x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(y\sec (x)\right)=2\sec(x)\tan(x)$$
$$\int d\left(y\sec (x)\right)=\int 2\sec(x)\tan(x)dx$$
$$y\sec(x)=2\sec(x)+C$$
$$y=C\cos (x)+2$$

Comment: How did you get the following $d(\frac{y}{u})$?

Comment: well, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y}{u}\right)=y\frac{-1}{u^2}\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{1}{u}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{yu'}{u^2}+\frac{y'}{u}\tag1$$ Similarly, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)=-\frac{-1}{u^2}\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{u'}{u^2}\tag2$$ Now, equate (1) & (2) to get $$-\frac{yu'}{u^2}+\frac{y'}{u}=-\frac{u'}{u^2}$$ $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y}{u}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$$ $$d\left(\frac{y}{u}\right)=d\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you neat trick working on the differentials.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\cos(x)y'+\sin(x)y&=2\sin(x)\\ u'y'+uy&=2u \end{align}$$
Then you can do nothing. It's better to write it this way:
$$\begin{align}uy'-u'y&=2\sin(x) \end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}uy'-u'y&=-2u'\end{align}$$
Where $u=\cos x$. Divide by$u^2$ both sides and integrate.
$$\dfrac  yu=-2\int \dfrac {du}{ u^2}$$